# granting permission to a library to a group which I do not want to have any access to the overall site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I want to give a certain group permission to contribute on a specific library but i dont not want to give them any read access or any access to the overall site. Can this be done? i have tried all options but no luck yet. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could set unique permission for the document library.

Go to Library settings -> Permissions for this document library -> Stop Inheriting Permissions -> Remove the certain group from existing permission groups -> Then grant the group with contribute permission.

Reference:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782

===================================

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I’m checking how the things are going on about this issue. Whether the answer helps you? If there is any problem with this issue, feel free to let me know.